# correct usage of String.matches() and regex

Tags: java, regex, match

Im trying to check if my input contains anything **but** `A-Z a-z , . ' - and whitespace`.
I guess it's a simple mistake because im quite a rookie when it comes to regex.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      doesMatch(0,"Hello ', . - ");
      doesMatch(1,"1Hello1");
      doesMatch(2,"23123");
      doesMatch(3,"§!$'##");
      doesMatch(4,"pe33teramjd");
      doesMatch(5,"3pe33teramjd");
      doesMatch(6,"pe33teramjd3");
      doesMatch(7,"yup py");
    }
  
  static void doesMatch(int number,String input){
      System.out.println("Number: "+number+" | "+input.matches("[^A-Za-z,.'\\s-]"));
  }
}
```

output:

```
Number: 0 | false
Number: 1 | false
Number: 2 | false
Number: 3 | false
Number: 4 | false
Number: 5 | false
Number: 6 | false
Number: 7 | false
```

desired output:

```
Number: 0 | false
Number: 1 | true
Number: 2 | true
Number: 3 | true
Number: 4 | true
Number: 5 | true
Number: 6 | true
Number: 7 | false
```

Comment: Your regex will only match a single character. `Pattern.compile(yourRegex).matcher(input).find()` will find it anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

> Im trying to check if my input contains anything but `A-Z a-z , . ' - and whitespace`.

Or, the reverse logic: You are trying to verify whether the text only consists of `A-Z a-z , . ' - and whitespace`.

You likely intended to repeat your regex pattern. So `[...]+` instead of just `[...]`, which would match a single character only.

Then, get rid of the `^` which would negate the expression. Also, you have to escape the `.`, so `\\.`, otherwise it matches any character and not the `.` (dot).

The regex pattern now is `"[A-Za-z,\\.'\\s-]+"`. Now you receive the following output:

```
Number: 0 | true
Number: 1 | false
Number: 2 | false
Number: 3 | false
Number: 4 | false
Number: 5 | false
Number: 6 | false
Number: 7 | true
```

Just negate the boolean with `!` and you are done.

---

For reference, the full code:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
      doesMatch(0,"Hello ', . - ");
      doesMatch(1,"1Hello1");
      doesMatch(2,"23123");
      doesMatch(3,"§!$'##");
      doesMatch(4,"pe33teramjd");
      doesMatch(5,"3pe33teramjd");
      doesMatch(6,"pe33teramjd3");
      doesMatch(7,"yup py");
    }
  
  static void doesMatch(int number,String input){
      System.out.println("Number: "+number+" | "+ !input.matches("[A-Za-z,\\.'\\s-]+"));
  }
}
```

---

### Without negation

If you do not want to negate the final result with `!` you have to correctly negate the regex pattern, which would informally be *"if any character is not A-Z a-z , . ' - or whitespace then it matches"*

A pattern checking that could be

```
".*[^A-Za-z,\\.'\\s-].*"
```

The `.*` means any character sequence.

---

### Search instead of full match

Instead of attempting a full-match, this is likely better done by having a regex search using `find()`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z,\\.'\\s-]");
...
boolean result = pattern.matcher(input).find();
```

This will now tell you whether it found anything matching the regex, so any character that is **not** `A-Za-z,\\.'\\s-`.